# Using LINQ to query XML and return empty string if no data is present

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq, rss

What I'm trying to do is to write a generic rss reader that I plug in any URL into without worry if the feed has all the *common* properties.  For instance in my example below I'm looking for **pubDate**, however if no **pubDate** exists in the xml I'd like to return the current Date.  I cannot seem to get the syntax right though.  Any suggestions?

```
Dim xmldoc As New XDocument
xmldoc = XDocument.Load(url)

Dim feeds = From feed In xmldoc.Descendants("item") Select New With { _
    Key .Title = feed.Element("title").Value, _
    Key .Link = feed.Element("link").Value, _
    Key .Description = feed.Element("description").Value, _
    Key .PubDate = If(feed.Element("pubDate").Value Is Nothing, Date.Now.ToString, feed.Element("pubDate").Value)}

For Each item In feeds
    Response.Write("<a href=""" & item.Link & """ target=""_blank"">" & item.Title & "</a> - " & item.PubDate & "<br />")
    Response.Write(item.Description & "<hr />")
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `feed.Element("pubDate").Value Is Nothing` write `feed.Element("pubDate") Is Nothing`!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Key .PubDate = IIf(feed.Element("pubDate") Is Nothing, Date.Now.ToString, feed.Element("pubDate").Value)
```

Comment: That's strange, since it's the same as mine!